# Why isn't null working properly in a while-loop?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null

```js
var age = "";
while( (age == "") || (age != null) && || isNaN(age)) {
    age = prompt("How old are you?");
}
if (age <= 14){
    alert("You're too young!");
} else if (age >= 15) {
    alert("Welcome on board!");
}
```

I'm not allowed to use functions for this exercice and I can't figure out why the prompt gives me `You're too young` when I click cancel. I know that I should use functions in order to solve this but I've been asked not to.

```
            var age = "";
while( (age == "") || (age != null) && || isNaN(age)) {
    age = prompt("How old are you?");
}
if (age <= 14){
    alert("You're too young!");
} else if (age >= 15) {
    alert("Welcome on board!");
}
```

Comment: `&& ||` is invalid syntax. It does not give `You're too young`, it gives `SyntaxError`

Comment: "While age is not an empty string"… It starts out as empty string, so that condition is immediately false and the loop is never entered. You probably want "while age *is* an empty string *or* is null *or* is NaN"…

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry that was a typo.

Comment: @deceze I'm still getting `You're too young` when I click cancel with the edited code.

Comment: Your whole Logic is wrong. Consider reconstructing it.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a do-while to get a valid value first instead of starting with "", then use parseInt to always get a number (or NaN on failure to parse)

```
var age;
do
{
  age = parseInt(prompt("How old are you?"), 10);
} while (isNaN(age))

if (age <= 14) {
  alert("You're too young!");
}
else if (age >= 15) {
  alert("Welcome on board!");
}
```